# Why is shower water temperature not adjustable?

Tags: shower, hot-water, temperature, cartridge

The temperature in my Hansgrohe Thermo Balance shower is always the same, no matter which way I turn the knob. It's generally warm enough to shower, but I cannot adjust it neither hotter nor colder. It uses a push-and-turn mechanism to adjust. The temperature adjustment is working correctly for all the other sinks and showers in my house. I tried adjusting the maximum temperature on the cartridge, but that had no effect. Do I need a new cartridge or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Has it always been this way?   a new valve??

Comment: @JACK No, problem started recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thermostatic controllers typically become calcified over time. This can result in the temperature not setting properly when you adjust it or even vibration and/or knocking in the valve. Sometimes just turning the knob rapidly several times from stop to stop will loosen things up. The manufacturer also provides videos on cleaning the valve which you should try if you haven't done it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTmyay1LAyY
If none of this works you'll probably have to replace the cartridge which is a fairly simple procedure if you're handy at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestions, but the problem remained. Called the manufacturer and explained the problem, and they said when customers have experienced this problem in the past, the cartridge needed to be replaced. Went ahead and purchased a new one.